# Behavior of static methods on websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm relatively new to web development, and I just found out that static variables are shared among users who are using the same webpage at the same time (new to me since I'm used to local application development).

Upon learning this, I'm wondering whether or not this applies to static methods as well? If two users are using a webpage and they call the same static method at the same time with different parameters, will they receive the correct results, or can the data end up mixing somehow and give them the same results?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've only been doing web development for about a month and a half.

Comment: Static methods execution is not related until they use only local variables (you'll get expected result of each method separately). When they start using some shared state (through static fields, or through same arguments, passed to them by reference), you may get unexpected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the methods are using static state of some sort, then very possibly, yes.

If they aren't using any static state then multiple calls to the method have no way to interact with each other and therefore won't interfere with each other.

Comment: I thought so, but I wasn't sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the static methods are self contained, they will return the correct results. However, if they rely on outside static variables, then they will return results that may or may not be what you intended.

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public static int Y = 5;

     public static int Add(int X)
     {

          return X += Y;
     }
}
```

Since Y is static, the results of first calling `Add(2)` will be 7, but afterwards calling `Add(3)` will be 10. That may or may not be what you intended.

Comment: You explanation implies that your example is actually `return X += Y;` which is not what it currently contains.

Comment: Example is very unclear how this demonstrate interaction between methods. Maybe you meant modifying the Y inside method?